# Bootstrap flex wrap is not working as intended in the last row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

Inside a webpage I need to organize a series of similar cards. So I used the `d-flex` and `flex-wrap` for the elements container and `flex-fill` for the elements themselves to make the layout as neat as possible.

```
<div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill">Flex item 1</div>
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill">Flex item 2</div>
    ...
    <div class="p-2 flex-fill">Flex item 14</div>
</div>
```

while I was expecting these classes make the layout like this:
[image]
they've actually formed the layout like this:
[image]
which is not what I meant considering the items look really weird when they stretch more than how they intended to.

Comment: please add your code  , for better explanation

Comment: @NancyH. The code is what i've mentioned in the post. It's pure html cause i haven't used any css of my own and it's all bootstrap

Comment: your style "flex-fill" is actually flex-grow property...avoid that flex-fill